# Find best scoring assignment of customers to products

Tags: algorithm

I got this programming question in an difficult interview's last round.

So the question has two lists of same size.

```
List<Customer>, List<Products>
```

There is a function which is like follows

`int score(Customer, Product)` and returns a score.

I have to the find an assignment of all the customer to products where score should be maximum.

It seems like an NP-complete problem and unlikely to be solved by me in the interview especially when I still couldn't a few days after the interview. Now I am just curious to know the solution.
Can anyone please help?

Comment: Please post some code.

Comment: I'm sure the question was very difficult, but you've just succeeded to make it even harder :|

Comment: Mauren - code is not important, if we tell him "it is NP problem" he is obviously able to do it himself...

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matching_(graph_theory)#Maximum_matchings_in_bipartite_graphs

Comment: This is a fairly well known problem called "maximum matching in weighted bipartite graphs". It's certainly solvable polynomially.

Comment: I am thinking about heuristic, for example in "knapsack" problem, you can order items by effectivity (=price/weight) and adding it in order of most effective and it has only ~ 1% difference to the optimal value, while having O(n) compared to O(2^n)...

But here I really dont see any way how to use some heuristics, cause we have to get score by trying everything with everything....

Comment: us2012 - of course it is solved polynomially, the "hard way" with two for cycles comparing everything with everything is exactly O(n^2)

Comment: I just looked at it and though "hungarian algorithm".. as some people were here earlier, please guys, post an answer...

Comment: If I understand correctly, this kind of problem is solved pretty easily with SQL. You have a Customer table, a Product table and score(Customer, Product) gives you a third table: Orders. It's a matter of joining and max-aggregate.

Comment: @itmitică: no, you didn't understood it correctly.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath: Maybe Orders sounds too loosely given the assignment nature of this problem, but do you have an example for a real-world problem this solving algorithm is used in?

Comment: @itmitică: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_algorithm

Comment: Can you explain the objective "find an assignment of all the customer to products where score should be maximum"? Do you mean one customer to multiple products where each customer-to-product assignment is the maximum for that customer?

Comment: @KarolyHorvath: Yeah, I know, you are Hungarian :) I was talking about applications, real life palpable applications, for the requested algorithm and how examples of these applications may help the OP understand the topic. I wasn't trying to suggest he use SQL to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

You could model this as a weighted bipartite graph that you want to find a maximal match.

[Wikipedia on Matching](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matching_%28graph_theory%29#Maximum_matchings_in_bipartite_graphs) has this answer that may be useful:

> In a weighted bipartite graph, each edge has an associated value. A
>   maximum weighted bipartite matching is defined as a matching where the
>   sum of the values of the edges in the matching have a maximal value.
>   If the graph is not complete bipartite, missing edges are inserted
>   with value zero. Finding such a matching is known as the assignment
>   problem. It can be solved by using a modified shortest path search in
>   the augmenting path algorithm. If the Bellman–Ford algorithm is used,
>   the running time becomes O(V^2 E), or the edge cost can be shifted
>   with a potential to achieve O(V^2 log(V) + V E) running time with the
>   Dijkstra algorithm and Fibonacci heap. The remarkable Hungarian
>   algorithm solves the assignment problem and it was one of the
>   beginnings of combinatorial optimization algorithms. The original
>   approach of this algorithm needs O(V^2E) running time, but it could be
>   improved to O(V^2 log(V) + V E) time with extensive use of priority
>   queues.

Answer (score -1):

Here is a (Java) solution to "I have to the find an assignment of all the customer to products where score should be maximum".

For C customers and P products, it runs in O(CP) time.

Note that I have not tested this code since the definition of the score() function was not provided.

```
Map<Customer, Product> solve(List<Customer> customers, List<Product> products)
{
    Map<Customer, Product> result = new HashMap<Customer, Product>();

    for (Customer customer : customers)
    {
        int maxScore = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
        Product bestProduct = null;

        for (Product product : products)
        {
            int currentScore = score(customer, product);

            if (currentScore > maxScore)
            {
                maxScore = currentScore;
                bestProduct = product;
            }
        }

        if (bestProduct != null)
        {
            result.put(customer, product);
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: This won't give a matching, all customers might end up with the same product.

Comment: Where in the problem does it prohibit all customers ending up with the same product?

Comment: I admit that the question is not phrased properly, but most others seem to interpret it as a bipartite matching problem. Imo the problem you solve cannot be classified as a "difficult interview question".

Comment: If "most others" jump off a cliff, would that mean they're right? And who is to say that this solution isn't for a 'difficult interview question'? That's very subjective.